# Can anyone explain why this grammar cannot be parsed by an LL(1) parser?

Tags: parsing, grammar

I am struggling to understand why an LL(1) parser would not be able to parse this.

```
A ::= B PLUS A | B

B ::= NUM | ID
```

Comment: `A ::= B PLUS A | B` has to look ahead to figure out which rule to use. The `B` is ambiguous.

Comment: I see that makes sense, thank you.

Comment: Would you know how to make it suitable for an LL(1) parser by chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A ::= B PLUS A | B` has to look ahead to figure out which rule to use. The `B` is ambiguous.

You could add a new rule `A'` that goes to epsilon to remove the ambiguity:

```
A  ::= B A'
A' ::= PLUS A | epsilon
B  ::= NUM | ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The grammar is not LL. The two productions (alternatives) of non-terminal A share the same prefix, which is not accepted in LL parsing, i.e, the grammar should be factorized first.